# Submitting a Form in an included page does not refresh the page

Tags: php, html, forms, session, submit

I have a PHP page : **index.php**

Inside this page, I have included another PHP page that acts as a sidebar.

In this sidebar, there's a log in form.

the **sidebar.php** page starts by checking the SESSION, if there's a session, the form won't show up, if there's no session, the form will show up so that the guest can log in.

```
session_start();
$guest = true;
if(!isset($_SESSION["id"])){
     //This is a Guest
     $guest = true;
} else {
     //This is not a Guest
     $guest = false;
}
//Then there's the PHP codes that handles form submitting
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
     //In the end, if everything is valid
     $_SESSION["id"] = $userID;
}
```

Normally a page would refresh after submitting a form, in this case, I expected the included file to refresh, and after reloading again, I expected the log in form to disappear, because `$_SESSION["id"]` is now SET, but it didn't.

If I refresh the page (F5), the form is gone, and it works, but its not working directly after I submit the form, I tried to add.

```
header("Location: http://localhost/index.php");
```

Yet it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls call the submit action before session check,

```
session_start();
$guest = true;

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

     $_SESSION["id"] = $userID;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION["id"])){
     //This is a Guest
     $guest = true;
} else {
     //This is not a Guest
     $guest = false;
}
```

Comment: Form is submitting perfectly, the log in form disappears after refreshing the page manually, but it does not disappear after submitting the form (which reloads the page).

Comment: I was wrong, it worked when I switched their positions, thanks.